# Wordpress plugin cpage variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a plugin to hide the canonical element from the header on comment pages.

My complete plugin code is:

```
global $cpage; 
if($cpage > 1){
remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');
}
```

So if the comment page number is > 1 then it will remove the canonical.

If I have just the `remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');` without the IF then it works...but I am trying to use the variable $cpage (which gives the comment page number in wordpress) to remove only on the comment pages...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function kill_comments_canonical() {
  global $cpage; 
  if(!empty($cpage) && $cpage > 1){
    remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');
  }
}
add_action('wp_head','kill_comments_canonical',9);
```

You could have several problems with the original code. First, `$cpage` may not be set when you need it to be-- when that code in your plugin runs, so hook it to `wp_head` when it will be set. Secondly, you need to run your `remove_action` after `rel_canonical` is added but before it prints, hence the third priority parameter in the `add_action` on the last line. I came to that number via trail and error, by the way.

Comment: The 9 is a priority value. I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand why it existed.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, I will add that I changed the > 1 to > 0, and I think that was causing some problem in the original code too...

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work with the `IF` statement then `$cpage` is obviously not greater than 1. Try `echo $cpage;` before the `IF` statement to check the number you're getting.

Comment: I tried echoing out cpage, it returns a blank.  Is cpage not a global variable?  is there another way to get the comment page?

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like. You now know the issue though. You're not getting `$cpage`.

Comment: Check where it's being set.